# How to use webdriverjs chrome setNetWorkConditions

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Does anyone know how to use the webdriverjs `setNetworkConditions()` method found in the [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Driver.html#setNetworkConditions)?

My code is the following

```
        const chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()
        const chromeOptions = {
            'args': ['--headless', '--test-type', '--disable-extensions', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--no-sandbox', '--start-maximized', '--disable-infobars']
        }
        chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', chromeOptions)
        chromeCapabilities.set('browserName', config.browser)
        chromeCapabilities.set('acceptInsecureCerts', true)
        chromeCapabilities.set('networkConditions', {
            offline: false,
            latency: 50000
        })

        const driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities).build()
        
        driver.setNetworkConditions({
            offline: false,
            latency: 50000
        })
```

but when I run the test I get a `Property 'setNetworkConditions' does not exist on type 'ThenableWebDriver'.`  error.

The only other question I could find related to this was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55350148/how-do-you-set-network-throttling-in-selenium-using-javascript), but I had the same issue. I've been stuck with this for a couple of hours and can't seem to figure it out, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59588594

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to wait for your driver to be resolved.

With await:

```
const driver = await new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities).build()

await driver.setNetworkConditions({
            offline: false,
            latency: 50000
        })
```

`setNetworkConditions` is returning a Promise according to docs, so you might want to await that too.

Comment: It always something silly like that that. Thanks @ziale!